# Multiple watchers on the same value, how is performance?

Tags: performance, angularjs, angularjs-scope

#### Summary:

In AngularJs, if the same variable is used for data-binding in multiple places, will it cause this variable to be dirty-checked multiple times each $digest-cycle?

#### Longer question:

I want to print a variable from the scope in the template, but the application is really sensitive to performance. Suppose the template contains the following:

```
<div>{{variableInScope}}</div>
  <span class="{{variableInScope}}">We print {{variableInScope}} a lot!</span>
  <span class="{{variableInScope}}">We print {{variableInScope}} again!</span>
  ... snip ~100 lines ...
</div>
```

Will this cause the variable `variableInScope` to be checked once or 200 times each $digest cycle?

#### "Awful code! Why u no use NG-repeat?"

The code above is just an example to illustrate the question. I'm building a data-grid, and I can't use NG-repeat because it sets up a *lot* of watchers, causing the digest-time to go up above 2 seconds on the customer's computers.

#### "Just use ng-grid!"

NG-grid is awesome in a lot of ways, but for our use case it has the same problem: way to many ng-repeats, causing performance to drop. We really need to keep $digest time down to a minimum, because of the complexity of the rest of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `variableInScope` is not being watched for each of those 100+ lines.  But when the value changes, it will be updated in each of those instances.  If those were input fields with `ngModel` it would be different.  Watching can be more intense than updating the DOM, but most of the watchers are simple comparisons of the current value to the old value.

As far as multiple watchers, the performance cost is linear based on the complexly of the watcher, unless the watcher will change the value. In that case it has to run all of the watchers again.

Here is a demo to show all of the times the watcher is called with all of the `{{variableInScope}}`s.  The count is logged.  You can change the value to see the count change.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/VaeBJ/1/

Comment: Perfect, thank you! The value in question is actually the width of a table column, to be updated on drag'n'drop of the column's edge. So it should update infrequently, but this will allow the column to shrink/expand as the user drags, without creating a big burden on the $digest-time. Again, thanks for an excellent answer!